# subset or exclude certain elements from indices in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe DF with 8000 rows. I can get the rows 1001:2000 with `inds=1001:2000`. Is there a way I can combine the indices 1:1000 and 2001:8000? If so, what is the command(s)?

I ask because I am trying to run cross-validation on a dataset using KNN and in order to run `knn.predict` (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/knnflex/docs/knn.predict) , I need to store the training and test set indices.

Comment: inds2 <- c(1:1000, 2001:8000)

Answer (score 2):

Just rbind the rows?

```
rbind(df[1:1001,],df[2001:8000,])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
df[c(1:1000, 2001:8000), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing cross validation wouldn't you want to randomly select your test and training data?

The page you linked has a good example of doing this

```
# 5-fold cross-validation to select k for above example
fold <- sample(1:5,75,replace=TRUE)
cvpred <- matrix(NA,nrow=75,ncol=10)
for (k in 1:10)
  for (i in 1:5)
    cvpred[which(fold==i),k] <- knn.predict(train=which(fold!=i),test=which(fold==i),cl,kdist,k=k)
# display misclassification rates for k=1:10
apply(cvpred,2,function(x) sum(cl!=x))
```

That being said if you just want the indices you could do the following:

```
inds = c(1:1001,2001:8000)
```